# Select where Count less than 10 where column names are from 3 joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, sybase

I have three tables venue, concert and event. I am looking for a way of showing all details of venues which have been allocated less than two events including those with no allocations.  Event table gets details of venue indirectly from concert table using a join, No foreign in event for Venues but there is one for concert.

Below is a code but it doesn't work as expected

```
 SELECT v.venue_id, v.venue_name, COALESCE( x.cnt, 0 ) Venue_count FROM 
 venue v
 LEFT JOIN concert ct ON v.venue_id = ct.venue_id
 LEFT JOIN event e ON e.concert_id = ct.concert_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT concert_id, COUNT( * ) cnt
 FROM event
 GROUP BY concert_id )x ON ct.concert_id = x.concert_id
 GROUP BY Venue_count
 ORDER BY  `Venue_count` DESC
```

Comment: what is the output of above query ?

Comment: pls post expected output (as text, no images), actual output, sample data (script create table and insert).

Comment: Are you really using MySQL, Oracle, SQLite and Sybase here? One of the rarest combinations ever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query can be written in an easier way

```
select  v.venue_id, v.venue_name
from    venue v
left join
        concert ct
on      v.venue_id = ct.venue_id
left join
        event e
on      e.concert_id = ct.concert_id
group by v.venue_id, v.venue_name
having   count(distinct e.event_id) < 2
```

This will go from `venues` to `concerts` and from `concerts` to `events`, counting the number of events for each venue and returning only those with less than two. Venues with no allocations will be preserved by the usage of `left join`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact Solution i was looking for.

Comment: Do you know why it cant work on oracle the error is near Count select  v.venue_id ID, v.venue_name Name, v.venue_address Address,
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Have you tried adding `v.venue_address` to your `group by` clause?

Comment: Thank you, after adding they now work thank you a lot